# Triangle to AABB collision code not working

Tags: c++, math, collision-detection, game-development, separating-axis-theorem

I have been tweaking and reworking my code to test an AABB against a triangle and I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I am using separating axis theorem as I believe this is the best and only way used to detect collisions between an AABB and Triangle (correct me if I am wrong or if there is a better/faster method). Currently it does not detect anything when a collision happens.

The code is relatively small, calling isAABBIntersectingTriangle every frame, hopefully someone who knows about math or the algorithm can help me out. The function takes in a bounding box min and max as two 3D vectors(glm::vec3) and the 3 of the triangles vertices (tri1, tri2, tri3) as glm::vec3s. These coordinates are both in world space (AABB coords translates by the position and scale only, triangle translated by position rotation and scale)

```
bool SATTriangleAABBCheck(glm::vec3 axis, glm::vec3 bboxMin, glm::vec3 bboxMax, glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2, glm::vec3 tri3)
{
    //Dot triangle vertices
    float triVert1 = glm::dot(axis, tri1);
    float triVert2 = glm::dot(axis, tri2);
    float triVert3 = glm::dot(axis, tri3);

    float triMin = glm::min(glm::min(triVert1, triVert2), triVert3);
    float triMax = glm::max(glm::max(triVert1, triVert2), triVert3);

    //Dot cube vertices
    float v1 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMin.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMin.z));
    float v2 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z));
    float v3 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMin.z));
    float v4 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMax.z));
    float v5 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMin.z));
    float v6 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMin.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z));
    float v7 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMin.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMax.z));
    float v8 = glm::dot(axis, glm::vec3(bboxMin.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMin.z));

    float aabbMin = glm::min(glm::min(glm::min(glm::min(glm::min(glm::min(glm::min(v1, v2), v3), v4), v5), v6), v7) ,v8);
    float aabbMax = glm::max(glm::max(glm::max(glm::max(glm::max(glm::max(glm::max(v1, v2), v3), v4), v5), v6), v7), v8);

    if ((triMin < aabbMax && triMin > aabbMin) || (triMax < aabbMax && triMax > aabbMin))
        return true;
    if ((aabbMin < triMax && aabbMin > triMin) || (aabbMax < triMax && aabbMax > triMin))
        return true;

    return false;
}

glm::vec3 CalcSurfaceNormal(glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2, glm::vec3 tri3)
{
    glm::vec3 u = tri2 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 v = tri3 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 nrmcross = glm::normalize(glm::cross(u, v));
    return nrmcross;
}

bool isAABBIntersectingTriangle(glm::vec3 bboxMin, glm::vec3 bboxMax, glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2,  glm::vec3 tri3)
{   
    //AABB face normals
    glm::vec3 axis1(1, 0, 0);
    glm::vec3 axis2(0, 1, 0);
    glm::vec3 axis3(0, 0, 1);

    //Triangle face normal
    glm::vec3 axis4 = CalcSurfaceNormal(tri1, tri2, tri3);

    //Edge normals
    glm::vec3 e1 = tri2 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 e2 = tri3 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 e3 = tri3 - tri2;
    glm::vec3 e4 = glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z) - glm::vec3(bboxMin.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z);
    glm::vec3 e5 = glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z) - glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMin.y, bboxMax.z);
    glm::vec3 e6 = glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMax.z) - glm::vec3(bboxMax.x, bboxMax.y, bboxMin.z);

    //Cross products of each edge
    glm::vec3 axis5 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e1, e4));
    glm::vec3 axis6 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e1, e5));
    glm::vec3 axis7 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e1, e6));
    glm::vec3 axis8 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e2, e4));
    glm::vec3 axis9 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e2, e5));
    glm::vec3 axis10 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e2, e6));
    glm::vec3 axis11 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e3, e4));
    glm::vec3 axis12 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e3, e5));
    glm::vec3 axis13 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e3, e6));


    //If no overlap on all axes
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis1, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis2, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis3, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis4, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis5, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis6, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis7, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis8, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis9, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis10, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis11, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis12, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;
    if (!SATTriangleAABBCheck(axis13, bboxMin, bboxMax, tri1, tri2, tri3)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Also here is the code in the main loop that calculates the world position of the triangle and then calls the function, I don't believe anything is wrong here as it's probably been looked over the most:

```
glm::vec3 tri1 = glm::vec3(entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[0]].position.x * entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[0]].position.y * entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[0]].position.z * entities[0]->scale);
    glm::vec3 tri2 = glm::vec3(entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[1]].position.x * entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[1]].position.y * entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[1]].position.z * entities[0]->scale);
    glm::vec3 tri3 = glm::vec3(entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[2]].position.x * entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[2]].position.y * entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->model.meshes[0].vertices[entities[0]->model.meshes[0].indices[2]].position.z * entities[0]->scale);

    //Translate these tris by the model matrix
    glm::mat4 mat(1.0f);
    mat = glm::translate(mat, glm::vec3(entities[0]->xPos, entities[0]->yPos, entities[0]->zPos));
    mat = glm::rotate(mat, glm::radians(entities[0]->xRot), glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
    mat = glm::rotate(mat, glm::radians(entities[0]->yRot), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
    mat = glm::rotate(mat, glm::radians(entities[0]->zRot), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    mat = glm::scale(mat, glm::vec3(entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->scale, entities[0]->scale));
    glm::vec4 tri11 = mat * glm::vec4(tri1.x, tri1.y, tri1.z, 1.0f);
    glm::vec4 tri22 = mat * glm::vec4(tri2.x, tri2.y, tri2.z, 1.0f);
    glm::vec4 tri33 = mat * glm::vec4(tri3.x, tri3.y, tri3.z, 1.0f);


    if (isAABBIntersectingTriangle(entities[3]->bboxMin, entities[3]->bboxMax, glm::vec3(tri11.x, tri11.y, tri11.z), glm::vec3(tri22.x, tri22.y, tri22.z), glm::vec3(tri33.x, tri33.y, tri33.z)))
    {
        std::cout << "AABB Tri collision\n";
    }
```

Comment: One part of constructing a good [mre] (MRE) is supplying inputs. In your case, it might be useful to choose a triangle and AAB that should intersect, then step through your code with those inputs to see which condition is triggering `return false`. (You can do this in a test program, rather than the program that calls this function every frame.) Next, do that calculation by hand to see what the result should be. (Did I mention that you should choose simple inputs? ;) )

Comment: Ah, you updated your code example. That's a rather complicated way to get your data for a MRE. How about something simpler, like `glm::vec4 tri11 = glm::vec4(4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);` or whatever numbers you decide to work with? Remember, we are testing one piece at a time, not your entire program at once. Right now the focus is on `isAABBIntersectingTriangle()`.

Comment: Yeah so in the code (I just editted it at the bottom) you can see I am only testing a single triangle from a mesh against a particular AABB. In fact, I am even drawing the exact triangle and AABB (boinding box itself) in space to make sure that I can see the exact coordinates of the colliding coordinates that are getting passed in. In a particular spot, it doesn't fail. In some spots, it doesn't get passed the first test (face normal test of the triangle) and in some cases it passes the face normal tests and a few of the axis tests.

Comment: I just punched in coordinates so that a triangles face is intersecting the AABB, only the face. Nothing happened, I modified one of the triangle coords a bit and it got set off (changes a y coord so a vertex or an edge was in) and it set off. Changed it so that the top point of the triangle and the two top edges were intersecting, nothing printed out. Seems like its an issue in my actual SAT code. It should be setting off by just detecting the face in the first place. Unsure what to try next, I've messed with the SAT code a lot already

Comment: `if (CollisionHelper::isAABBIntersectingTriangle(glm::vec3(-1, 0, -1), glm::vec3(-2, 1, -2), glm::vec3(-3.0f, -0.5f, -1.5f), glm::vec3(0, -0.5f, -1.5f), glm::vec3(-1.5f, 1.5f, -1.5f)))
    {
        std::cout << "AABB Tri collision\n";
    }` is the new code just to show what coordinates I am using (first are the AABB min and max, then the 3 triangle vertex coords)

Comment: Update: it is passing the axis test of the 3 triangle AABBs and the surface normal of the triangle (in this instance the normals for these 4 are either 0 or 1 so they are perfectly aligned normals). The first edge test is where it is failing/messing up now at SATTriangleAABBCheck with axis 5)

Comment: If someone knows, am I calculating the edge normals correctly? Subtract the coordinates to get the desired edge and then cross an edge with the edge of the other triangle and the normalize it? Really thinking that these edge axes are the issue now.

Comment: Another update: axis 5 is returning nan(ind), nan(ind), nan(ind) for each coordinate where as every other coordinate is returning a proper value/ Anyone know what would be giving axis5 nan(ind) for each value??? e1 = (3, 0, 0) and e4 = (-1, 0, 0)

Comment: Hypothesis: What happens if you try to normalize a zero-length vector? (Try it.) What would make a cross-product have a length of zero?

Comment: I just discovered that's it. The cross product is a zero zero zero vector and then I normalize it. That makes sense. What do I do in this case, is 0, 0, 0 a valid axis to test against? Did I calculate something wrong? Should I just check if any axes are zero and skip if so? I don't quite understand why I would get a zero zero zero axis and if I can check against it and what to do. No paper on collision detection or SAT has covered this

Comment: A cross-product gives a vector perpendicular to the two factors, made unique by the right-hand rule. When vectors are parallel, the right-hand rule fails (there are too many vectors perpendicular to the factors) and the cross-product is zero. How to resolve this depends on the situation. I'd guess that the test simplifies in this case (*maybe* skip the check?), but I haven't worked through everything that you're doing.

Comment: I found another thread that says you just skip it. I skipped the check and I am getting correct results now. Messed with that a bit and it seems to be correct with the values I manually enter. Now the values I was plugging in before are kind of working but not fully. It only detects collision if the AABB is around the center of the triangle, and the height is roughly not accurate too. Not sure if this is some fault with me calculating the triangle coords incorrectly (I don't think because I have checked these coords already). What should I check next?

Comment: Update: I was just passing in the wrong sized coords, everything works as expected now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a section of code in the test that is not robust.

> ```
> glm::vec3 axis5 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e1, e4));
> glm::vec3 axis6 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e1, e5));
> glm::vec3 axis7 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e1, e6));
> glm::vec3 axis8 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e2, e4));
> glm::vec3 axis9 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e2, e5));
> glm::vec3 axis10 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e2, e6));
> glm::vec3 axis11 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e3, e4));
> glm::vec3 axis12 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e3, e5));
> glm::vec3 axis13 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(e3, e6));
> ```

These calculations are made unconditionally. However, normalizing a vector works only when the vector's length is not zero. A cross product has a zero length when the factors are parallel. So if any of `e1, e2, e3` are parallel to any of `e4, e5, e6`, then the corresponding cross product will be a zero-length vector, and the coordinates of the normalization will be [NaN](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nan).

A big problem with NaN is that it "poisons" all calculations. In particular, a single NaN coordinate in a vector is enough to cause any dot product involving that vector to evaluate to NaN. This really messes with what `SATTriangleAABBCheck` tries to do. (A zero-length vector would similarly mess with the function, so skipping the normalization is not a solution.)

The solution depends on what should be done in the case where a cross product is zero. In this case, that zero means that the calculation failed to produce a separating axis. There are fewer than the maximal number of axes to check because distinct parallel lines never intersect. Skip the test on the zero axis (that was normalized to NaN).